# Can't figure this problem need help please

Tags: homework-and-exercises, crystals

[image]

A two-dimensional centered rectangular lattice structure is shown below in Fig. 1. 
 Choose the appropriate direct lattice vectors (a1 and a2) associated with a primitive cell (smallest unit cell), then calculate the reciprocal lattice vectors (b1 and b2).

Comment: a₁=0.4mmî and a₂=0.3mmĵ